# something wrong with getElemenByName

Tags: javascript, helper

```
function show(name,age)
{
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName("radio");
    function show()
    {
       if (x.name==="true")
       {
          alert("true");
       }
    }
}
```

plz guys help.I've got problem,nothing happens,I want my script to make alert function if radio is clicked and input name is true

Comment: `if (x[0].name==="true")`

Comment: What's the point of the nested function?

Comment: Please, be more professional! "plz" and the name is misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

The [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) function returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), a "live" array which changes as the DOM changes.

You have to select an element from the collection to be able to do anything with that element, so change `x.name` to `x[0].name`.

**EDIT:**
also I noticed that you are searching for the "radio" tag name, but you are using an input tag, so that document.getElementsByTagName call probably didn't return the tag you wanted anyway.

You probably want:
`document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

Comment: nothing probably happens because `x[0].name` probably is not a string called `"true"`, you should figure out if that is the comparison you want.

Comment: also I noticed that you are searching for the "radio" tag name, but you are using an input tag, so that `document.getElementsByTagName ` call probably didn't return the tag you wanted anyway